# Don't know where to start (GPA Calculator in C)

Tags: c

I want to create a GPA calculator program in C, the details are:

Staff administrator mode

1. Enter a student’s details, e.g. name and student ID (ID format is fixed, e.g. KPKL12345)
2. Enter a student’s course details, e.g. course code, credit hours, grade obtained, current
   semester session
3. Generate the student’s semester GPA score
4. Generate the student’s CGPA score
5. View the student’s GPA score
6. View the student’s CGPA score

Student mode

1. Enter student ID to log in (ID format is fixed, e.g. KPKL12345)
2. The GPA and CGPA scores are displayed for student’s view

I don't know how would we store multiple students' details in variable(s)? And how to display them after. And not sure how to continue after that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char studentID[10], studentName[20], courseCode[8], grade[2];
    int mode, creditHR;

    printf(" ========================================\n");
    printf("             GPA Calculator\n");
    printf(" ========================================\n");
    printf("          Please select a mode\n");
    printf("       --------------------------\n");
    printf("       1. Administrator Mode\n"); 
    printf("       2. Student Mode\n");
    printf("       3. Exit\n\n");
    printf("  >");
    scanf("%d", &mode);

    if (mode == 1) {
        printf("Please enter a student ID > ");
        scanf("%c", &studentID);

    }

    else if (mode == 2) {

    }

    else if (mode ==3) {
        printf("Thank you for using");
    }

    else {
        printf("Invalid Mode");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far (not done yet), another problem is: The program would stop running after I insert my mode, like when I type "1" for admin mode, it displays "Please enter a student ID" after and the program ends. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Read closely the documentation of `scanf`. `scanf("%c", &studentID)` -> `scanf("%s", studentID)`, but with that you cannot enter student names containing spaces (don't care, deal with this later).

Comment: "Re: The program would stop running after I insert my mode, like when I type "1" for admin mode, it displays "Please enter a student ID" after and the program ends." ===> That is because you simply return from `main()` after checking if `mode == 1`.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &studentID);` ==> invokes undefined behavior. The `%c` format specifier expects a pointer to a `char`, but `&studentID` has type `char (*)[10]`. You are looking for the `%s` format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly I want to help with program flow and present some ideas.  This
code will keep running until user wishes to exit (mode 3).   Others
have commented -- this code also addresses some of those issues but
not all -- the rest is up to you.  This code may contain errors/problems  for you to fix.  Best wishes...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STUDENTS 20

void do_student_ops()
{
    printf("Welcome to Student Mode\n");
}


int main() 
{
    char studentName[MAX_STUDENTS][20], 
        courseCode[MAX_STUDENTS][8], grade[MAX_STUDENTS][2];
    int mode, creditHR[MAX_STUDENTS], studentID[MAX_STUDENTS];
    int done = 0, which_student =0;

    printf(" ========================================\n");
    printf("             GPA Calculator\n");
    printf(" ========================================\n");
    printf("          Please select a mode\n");
    printf("       --------------------------\n");
    printf("       1. Administrator Mode\n"); 
    printf("       2. Student Mode\n");
    printf("       3. Exit\n\n");

    while(!done)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a selection:>");
        scanf("%d", &mode);

        switch(mode)
        {
            case 1: /* Admin mode */
                printf("\nPlease enter a student ID > ");
                scanf("%d", &studentID[which_student]);  /* one idea to handle this -- not complete or workable*/
            break;

            case 2: /* Student mode */
                do_student_ops();  /* create a function for doing student mode */
            break;

            case 3: /* Quit prog */
                printf("\nThank you for using\n");
                done = 1;
            break;

            default:
                printf("\nInvalid Mode\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```